# Understanding Objective-C method value passing

Tags: objective-c, methods, variable-assignment, assign

Lets say I have in viewDidLoad:

```
NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
[self doSomethingWithArray:entries];

NSLog(@"%@", entries);
```

Then in method I have:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)entries
{
    // create some custom data here, lets say - Something *something...
    [entries addObject:something];
}
```

How is it possible that entries (one at the top) now (after method is finished) contain object something, since object "something" is not added to property or instance variable, and nslog will log class "Something" ? And doSomethingWithArray doesn't return anything since its "void".

I have encountered this for first time and dunno if there is any name of this appearance ?

I have seen this for second time in some examples and really dunno how its done.

If anyone could explain this a bit whats happening here I would be very very grateful.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Because Objective-C instances are passed by reference (as you can tell by the `*` pointer syntax). You basically pass the address of the array to the `doSomethingWithArray:` method. In that method you add something to the array referenced by that address. And of course once the method returns, your array will contain that new object.

Comment: Just one more question similar to this one. Under 3) here http://www.raywenderlich.com/33804/how-to-make-a-letterword-game-with-uikit-part-1 . So When you assign self.controller.gameView = gameLayer; - that means whenever you change gameView in self.controller (actually inside GameViewController class) it will change gameLayer added to the view ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the *something* object to the array, the array always retains it i.e it maintains copy of the ***Something*** object.

So NSLog prints the *something*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you add an object to an array, it does retain the object, but IT DOES NOT MAINTAIN A COPY. The array simply contains the pointer to the ORIGINAL object, whose retain count is increased.

Comment: Yes @ReinhardMänner, you are right. Since the person who asked the question seemed new to objectiveC, so to keep the language simple and understandable I wrote the copy thing